# Nancy Self host get list of all connected clients` IPs

Tags: c#, nancy, self-hosting

I have a console application in C# with nancy self host, it currently works well, we can access session data with the `Request.Session` object. My question is how can we get a list of all the connected clients in a module or Program class? like a list of ips and session ids so that we can access any connected client's session object.
Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box that you can give you that however you can try something like :

```
 public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Nancy.Session.ISession> Clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Nancy.Session.ISession>();

 protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context){
   base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
   clients.TryAdd(context.Request.UserHostAddress, context.Request.Session);
}
```

Comment: i get this error `Session support is not enabled` inside the **RequestStartup** method each time i open the url on the browser, which makes me think am on the right path, something is missing...

Comment: I think the session object is not available until after **RequestStartup**